# Executable behaving differently when run through WMI compared to run locally

Tags: c#, python, python-3.x, wmi, executable

I have the following c sharp file compiled as an executable.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace Foreground {
  class GetForegroundWindowTest {

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling=true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
    public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

    public static void Main(string[] args){
        while (true){
            IntPtr fg = GetForegroundWindow(); //use fg for some purpose

            var bufferSize = 1000;
            var sb = new StringBuilder(bufferSize);

            GetWindowText(fg, sb, bufferSize);

            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("C:\\Office Viewer\\OV_Log.txt")) 
            {
                sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss,") + sb.ToString());
            }

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this executable on a local machine it yields both the date and the name of the current window.

when I run this executable from a remote machine using wmi it yields date and the name of the current window is blank, which I assume means that it returns null.  Does anyone have a fix for this?

The program which runs the wmi executable is written in python, and is of the form:

```
import wmi

IP         = '192.168.165.x'
USERNAME   = 'username'
PASSWORD   = 'password'
REMOTE_DIR = 'c:\ ... \'

remote_pc = wmi.WMI (IP, user = USERNAME, password = PASSWORD)

exe_remote_path = join (['\\\\', IP, '\\', REMOTE_DIR, filename)

remote_pc.Win32_Process.Create (CommandLine = exe_remote_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be the issue.....

> For security reasons the Win32_Process.Create method cannot be used to start an interactive process remotely.

from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389388%28VS.85%29.aspx)